# How to display special character in RichEdit control

Tags: nsis, richedit, nsdialogs

I am using following code.

```
  nsDialogs::CreateControl "RichEdit20A" ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${WS_VSCROLL}|${ES_MULTILINE}|${ES_WANTRETURN} ${__NSD_Text_EXSTYLE} 30% 30% 65% 45% ``
  Pop $0

 ;load the license from file 

nsRichEdit::Load $0 $PLUGINSDIR\license.txt
```

(Using NSIS RichEdit Plugin)

I have problem loading special characters. They should up as Â® or â€“ instead of copyright symbol or - 
I am using unicode version of NSIS and compiling on 32 bit machine. Can someone please provide suggestions for this.

Comment: How is license.txt encoded? UTF-16LE?

Comment: I do not know this one. I'l take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think there were an update in Unicode NSIS which fixes this issue. Try to use latest version 3.0a2.

Set **Unicode true** and use

```
nsDialogs::CreateControl "RichEdit20W" ...
```

The **W** mean Unicode version of RichEdit (A is for Ansi).

Comment: I am using the unicode NSIS from here http://www.scratchpaper.com/ I am still seeing the issue after changing to RichEdit20A. I dont the issue on 64 bit machine only on 32 bit machine.

Comment: Unicode true should be somewhere at the beginnnig of the script. It cannot be placed later because NSIS needs some routines to execute as first.

Comment: The RichEdit fix in the alpha was just for standard pages, not for custom pages like nsDialogs.